# Error: Update with select in MySQL 5

Tags: mysql-error-1093

Next everybody, I'm trying to make a query (UPDATE) to debit credits in XX (value) of a company identified by script_id + cnpj.
Ie, the value will dynamically and identification of the company as well.
 
When I run the following error appears:
[Err] 1093 - You can not specify target table 'company' for update in FROM clause
 
Already googled, tried to optimize the code, but did not see another way to perform this query.

```sql
UPDATE empresa  
SET saldo = saldo - ( 
        SELECT
        preco
    FROM
        preco_servico
    WHERE
        id = (
            SELECT
                emp2.idEscritorio
            FROM
                empresa AS emp2
            WHERE
                razao_social = (
                    SELECT
                        emp3.associacao
                    FROM
                        empresa AS emp3
                    WHERE
                        idEscritorio = (
                            SELECT
                                certidao_contratada.empresa_idEscritorio AS idEscritorio
                            FROM
                                certidao_contratada
                            INNER JOIN certidao_processada ON certidao_contratada.cnpj_idCnpj = certidao_processada.certidao_contratada_cnpj_idCnpj
                            WHERE
                                certidao_processada.certidao_contratada_scripts_idScript = 68 #script_id
                            AND certidao_processada.certidao_contratada_cnpj_idCnpj = '34.997.015/0001-98' #cnpj (da certidão)
                            ORDER BY
                                certidao_processada.dataHoraConcluido DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                        )
                )
        )
    AND tipo_servico LIKE 'b%'
)
WHERE
    emp1.idEscritorio = (
        SELECT
            certidao_contratada.empresa_idEscritorio AS idEscritorio
        FROM
            certidao_contratada
        INNER JOIN certidao_processada ON certidao_contratada.cnpj_idCnpj = certidao_processada.certidao_contratada_cnpj_idCnpj
        WHERE
            certidao_processada.certidao_contratada_scripts_idScript = 68 #script_id
        AND certidao_processada.certidao_contratada_cnpj_idCnpj = '34.997.015/0001-98' #cnpj (da certidão)
        ORDER BY
            certidao_processada.dataHoraConcluido DESC
        LIMIT 1
    );`
```

Comment: Did you bother reading the error messages? You can **NOT** update a table from which you're selecting at the same time.

Comment: I tried to change the alias, but still did not work!

Comment: Doesn't matter how you alias it. You cannot do an UPDATE or DELETE query on a table from which you are going a SELECT at the same time. MySQL simply does not allow it. It's like dissassembling a building from the bottom up, expecting the roof to stay in the same place the whole time.

Comment: ok. how can I solve this? no other way to perform this query?

Comment: select into a temporary table. then you can select from that temp table in your udpate query without the conflict.

Comment: how can I make using temporary table?